# Targeting an HTML element with Selenium using xpath

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I'm navigating a coworker's somewhat messy html in the process of writing a website testing program using Selenium WebDriver in Java. Things are going well so far (I've found and used several helpful suggestions from SO already), but I am stuck on how to target a particular element in this html.

```
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="col_1">
    <a target="content" href="link_text_omitted" class="no">RLS DISABILITY
    </a>
</td>
<td class="col_2">
    <a target="asdf" href="https://link_text_omitted">
    </a>
</td>
<td class="col_3">
</td>
<td class="col_4">$0.00 </td>
<td class="col_5">180/180- $3300.00</td>
<td class="col_6">
    <a target="content" href="link_text_omitted" class="ecurrent">$43.23
    </a> 
</td>
</tr>
```

I removed the specific URLs above for privacy reasons. I have about a dozen other `<tr>` elements on the page, formatted the same way, but with different text values and dollar amounts `(col_1, col_4, col_6)`. I need to access that $43.23 text in the `[td class="col_6"]`, as well as the $0.00 in the `[td class="col_4"]`. I can't just select it by the class name because I have many other elements on the page that are also `[td class="col_6"]` as well as [a class="ecurrent"].

The real identifying characteristics of this element with respect to the other similar ones are the "RLS DISABILITY" text in `[td class="col_1"]`, as well as some partial text in the URLs which have been omitted.

I've been trying to use some complicated xpath strings to get it, but I can't quite get what I want. The closest thing I have so far is this:

```
WebElement RLSDisabilityName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[a/text()='RLS DISABILITY']"));
```

Which I believe selects the first [td] (but I am not sure).

I think I could select the [a] tag with the $43.23 using By.partialText, but the partial text needed is quite a long piece of a URL, and I would like to make this portable for use on other similar websites.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Do you know in which row your element will be? I mean is it always within the first/second `tr` tag for example?

Comment: Try to convince your coworker to add some id attributes for you in the code...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right path, honestly.  Don't worry about portability, the HTML is simply not good enough for portability.

You can definitely do this with a XPath selector, and the one you have is definitely on the right path.

That said, another possibility is to create a `List<WebElement>` with each of the `td`s.  You can then iterate through the list and pull out the ones you like.  This way you will have access to methods like `getText()` and such.